# POST requests giving errors yet I give all Headers and Form Data

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a website, a login form is asked; I'm using the `requests` python 3.x module. I provide form_data and headers information just like what I could analyse on the Network Google Chrome developer console:

```
Payload = {
'form_data': {
    'login': 'MYLOGIN',
    'password': 'MYPASSWORD'},
'headers': {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'Origin': 'https://tastyworks.com',
    'Referer': 'https://tastyworks.com/',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36'
},
'url': 'https://tastyworks.com'
```

}

```
post_response = requests.post(
    Payload['url'], data=Payload['form_data'], headers=Payload['headers'])
```

When I want to print  `post_response` here is what I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>403 ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
This distribution is not configured to allow the HTTP request method that was used for this request. The distribution supports only cachable requests.

<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: YZ_tAajXFCioe5_fh6sVX4A4aPA_kSICtzKf2pkT76sPPj2R_WiOJg==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Here is the Network analysis: [Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQLFI.png)
Is this an authorization issue ? Or is this has to do with how I configured the request ?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Are you sure that sending login/password as plain form data is the correct way to log in?

Comment: looking at the website, the post url seems to be ```https://api.tastyworks.com/sessions```. Try it with that..

Comment: @JohnGordon I edited the post with an image !

Comment: @Xosrov Oh yes, that was it, and I assume you saw that in the 'General' headers, right ?

Comment: I see that you're submitting them as form data.  My question was, are you **supposed** to do it that way?  There are many different ways that websites can handle authentication.

Comment: @JohnGordon I guess I was sending this to the wrong URL, oops. Well I'm trying to access the website just like any user. Is this approach flawed ?

Comment: @Falanpin Yes, the method and url are in the General section

Comment: Did you GET the login page in a requests session and then use the session for the POST? The login GET often provides cookies needed for the POST. Keep using the session for all subsequent get/post.

Comment: @barny No I did not, I directly POST the correct login url, get a sessions ID, and I guess I will be using this to browse the website from now. Thanks all of this is new to me, really interesting !

Comment: ok so start a session with get and try again

Comment: @barny Oh you didn't understand, my issue was solved ! The url I was trying to reach was not the correct one